# How do I link directly to a specific PART of a blog post or online article? (e.g. to a paragraph or heading)

Tags: google-chrome, url, hyperlink, blogging, links

I want to link to some really cool PART of an article, like this [blog post announcing the card ageing power-up in Trello](http://blog.trello.com/introducing-power-ups-calendar-card-aging-and-more/), amongst other things.

What can I use, using Google Chrome, or in any browser in general, to produce a URL that when clicked, would link directly into that header? i.e. when a user follows the link, they should see the following:

- [image: blog page]

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In HTML, you can link to fragments by appending `#FRAGMENT` at the URL, where `FRAGMENT` is the value of an `id` attribute (on any element) or a `name` attribute (on an `a` or `area` element). The HTML author has to provide these attributes.

A manual way how to find these: Mark the whole content you want to link to, inspect the source code (usually rightclick and then something like "Show source"), and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> for `id=` and `name=`.

[XPointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPointer) is a specification that allows to link to any part of a XHTML document, even if the author didn’t provide any fragment identifiers. Currently you’d probably need a browser add-on (and so does the one you want to give the link to) to enable XPointer support.

For old versions of Firefox, there is [FXPointer](http://codedread.com/fxpointer/):

> How many times have you told a friend or colleague "Go to `http://example.com/some/doc` and search for XXXX" ? I do it a lot actually. In fact, this becomes increasingly important as the mobile web accelerates and small screens with harder-to-use keyboards become more prevalent. I would like to start creating links in my documents and blog posts that point exactly to some paragraph on the page. I hope the FXPointer Firefox extension will help.

Answer (score 3):

**You can't** (on this specific page). Linking to a particular subsection (such that a user's browser automatically scrolls to it) requires the use of HTML Anchors for each section, which that page does not have. More specifically, the heading would need to either contain or have nearby:

- An `A` (anchor) tag
- With an `id` or `name` property

If those criteria are met, then you can link to

```
http://example.com/webpage.html#anchorName
```

where `anchorName` is the value of the `name` or `id` property.

That Trello page just has a header though:

```
<h2>Card Aging</h2>
```

So it can't be linked to. If they had used instead:

```
<h2><a name="aging">Card Aging</a></h2>
```

then you could link to it like such:

```
http://blog.trello.com/introducing-power-ups-calendar-card-aging-and-more/#aging
```

Comment: As I suspected; I think a service that would address a particular smidgin of data on 'static' content with an XPath or something would actually be really useful.

Seems like the best you can do is to highlight a section with the mouse and store that subtree in applications like Evernote; then you share it that way.

I hope someone provides a fix for this situation...!

Comment: It's entirely up to the site developer.

Comment: Note that the `id` attribute can be used on any element, not only `a`.

Answer (score 2):

In modern versions of Chrome, you can use this special anchor: `#:~:text=ENCODED_TEXT_YOU_WANT_TO_LINK`.

https://www.howtogeek.com/658842/how-to-use-google-chromes-new-deep-linking-feature/

Comment: See [this answer on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15481911/linking-to-a-specific-part-of-a-web-page/72400036#72400036) for more details and practical examples.

Comment: This answer shows what the anchor would look like (just customize the part after the equal sign).  So, using this information, you may be able to generate a URL manually. 
 If you want to do things a bit more automated-like, here's some steps (in Google Chrome) : Highlight the text.  Right-click on it.  Choose "Copy link to highlight".  Now, your clipboard has URL that can be pasted.  Often I find that URL might contain more text than what I wanted, but it can be the easy way to make a URL quick (and then I can manually edit the URL if I want to).